# How to transform mongoose schema errors

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to transform **all** mongoose schema errors.

Let's say I've a UserSchema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
     type: String,
     unique: true,
     required: [true, 'E-Mail is required']
  },
  password: {
     type: String,
     required: [true, 'Password is required']
  }
}
```

If I would try to save a user without email and password, I would get following response:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "password": {
      "message": "Password is required",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Password is required",
        "path": "password"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "password"
    },
    "email": {
     // ...
    }
  },
  "_message": "User validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

I would like to transform this error response **globally** for all my schemas, for example to

```
{
  errors: [
      { message: "Password is required", path: "password" }
      // ...
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to apply a transform method **globally** to all Schema errors? (I would like to avoid to transform each response manually)

Answer (score 0):

```
var schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
var Man= db.model('Man', schema);

// This man has no name :(
var man = new Man();
man.save(function(error) {
  assert.equal(error.errors['name'].message,
    'Path `name` is required.');

  error = man.validateSync();
  assert.equal(error.errors['name'].message,
    'Path `name` is required.');
});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem **globally**. I would like to have something like an interceptor, which is able to transform all errors in one place.